# Transforming chain of fluent expressions with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I have the following sample classes:

```
// Sample fluent style class
namespace Fluent
{
    public class FluentSample
    {
        private readonly IList<string> _options;

        public FluentSample()
        {
            _options = new List<string>();
        }

        public static FluentSample Build()
        {
            return new FluentSample();
        }

        public FluentSample WithOption(string option)
        {
            _options.Add(option);
            return this;
        }
    }
}

// Sample class that uses the one above
public class FooSample
{
    public void Build()
    {
        FluentSample.Build()
            .WithOption("uppercase")
            .WithOption("trim")
            .WithOption("concat");
    }
}
```

Suppose that I want to transform the code that uses the `FluentSample` class and replace `FluentSample.Build()` with `Fluent.FluentSample.Build().WithOption("addnewline")`. In order to do that, I need to make sure that it's really calling that class (and not another with the same name), what demands some symbol binding.

From the Syntax Visualizer window, I've found that it's basically an `InvocationExpressionSyntax` node, so I'm overriding `VisitInvocationExpression` from `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`:

```
public class Rewritter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel SemanticModel;

    public Rewritter(SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {
        SemanticModel = semanticModel;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        var symbol = SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;
    }
}
```

However, the symbols I'm getting are the many `WithOption` calls. The syntax analysis shows that it contains a chain of expressions that only leads to more and more `WithOption`s. How can I check if this is really a call to `Fluent.FluentSample` and apply the transformation?

The original code is almost exactly like this, so the statements will always be in fluent style.

Comment: Where exactly is "at the end of the invocation"? Remember that people can write `var x = new FluentSample(); x.WithOption("a"); (x.WithOption("b")).WithOption(c);`. It would be a lot easier if you said "How can I check if this is really a call to `Fluent.FluentSample.Build()` and replace it with `Fluent.FluentSample.Build().WithOption("addnewline")`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about putting it that way. Also, the code will always be in fluent style, no need to cover edge cases. I've edited the question to clarify it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
public class Rewritter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel SemanticModel;

    public Rewritter(SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {
        SemanticModel = semanticModel;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        var symbol = SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

        // symbol could be null, e.g. when invoking a delegate
        if (symbol == null)
        {
            return base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);
        }

        // symbol must be called Build and have 0 parameters
        if (symbol.Name != "Build" ||
            symbol.Parameters.Length != 0)
        {
            return base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);
        }

        // TODO you might want to check that the parent is not an invocation of .WithOption("addnewline") already

        // symbol must be a method on the type "Fluent.FluentSample"
        var type = symbol.ContainingType;

        if (type.Name != "FluentSample" || type.ContainingSymbol.Name != "Fluent")
        {
            return base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);
        }

        // TODO you may want to add a check that the containing symbol is a namespace, and that its containing namespace is the global namespace

        // we have the right one, so return the syntax we want
        return
            SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(
                SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(
                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                    node,
                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("WithOption")),
                SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(
                    SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
                        SyntaxFactory.Argument(
                            SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(
                                SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                SyntaxFactory.Literal("addnewline"))))));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works the way I want. Just one correction: the syntax kind for the literal expression is `StringLiteralExpression` instead of `StringLiteralToken`.

Comment: @kopranb Indeed, typo fixed.